# nth element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add `hr` tag after fourth element which is working but but it broke my jquery which removes `padding-right` from the fourth element.

Without hr tag my jquery works fine

```
 $("div.container  > div:nth-child(4n+4)").css("padding-right", "0px");
```

but when i add

---

tag it just breaks the jquery in this case it removes padding from 4 div and 7th div as it counts

---

also as a child item.

I also tried

`$("div.container > div.image-wrapper:nth-child(4n+4)").css("padding-right", "0px");`

this didn't work event.

How can i modify it so that it only counts div's with class `image-wrapper` as it child's and remove padding from 4 & 8th div only.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="image-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="image-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="image-wrapper"></div>
    <hr class="video-divider-line">
    <div class="image-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="image-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="image-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="image-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="image-wrapper"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you created a demo fiddle?

Comment: Why do you need jQuery for this? Plan CSS is not enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [nth-of-type](http://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/)

```
$("div.container  > div:nth-of-type(4n+4)").css("padding-right", "0px");
```

Or

```
$("div.container  > .image-wrapper:nth-of-type(4n+4)").css("padding-right", "0px");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var $divs = $("div.container > div.image-wrapper");

for (var i = 3; i < $divs.length; i+=4) {
   $divs.eq(i).addClass('zero-padding');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RKUae/

Or:

```
.zero-padding { padding-right: 0 }

$("div.container > div.image-wrapper").addClass(function(i) {
    if (++i % 4 === 0) return 'zero-padding';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div.container .image-wrapper:eq(3),div.container .image-wrapper:eq(6)").css("padding-right", "0px");
```

reference [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)